# Django: How to properly use the ForeignKey in a modelform?

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I'm trying to create a HTML form in Django and I'm using [Django modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) to do this. In my models.py file I'm using a "ForeignKey", this will be converted to a drop-down menu with options in the HTML form. This works, I'm seeing a drop-down in my view.

**models.py**

```
class plants(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    active_account = models.ForeignKey('accounts')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('active_account', 'name')

class accounts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        url = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PlantsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = plants
        fields = '__all__'
```

**My_Cool_Django_ModelForm.html**

```
{% for field in form %}
{{ field.label_tag }}
{{ field|addcss:'form-control'}}
{% endfor %}
```

## Problem

So let's say I have 2 accounts in the database called "Mister Foo" and " Miss Bar". If I then load the HTML form I do see 2 options in my dropdown menu but not "Mister Foo" and "Miss Bar". It only drops down with the texts "accounts object" and I want it to display the names.

[image]

So my question, how can I display the accounts the dropdown by their name? :( I've tried field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__unicode__` for your `accounts` class:

```
class accounts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

By the way, it's **bad** code style to use `accounts` as python class name. It should be capfirst and single form like `Account`. Check [pep8 doc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) for convention details.

Comment: If you are using Python 3, define `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`.